Proving an Inequality Involving the Moment Generating Function
I am trying to prove the following inequality for an arbitrary random variable $X$ and a constant $c$:
$$P(X\ge c)\le \min_{s\ge 0}e^{-sc}M_X(s),$$
where $M_X(s)$ is the moment generating function of $X$.
Here is my attempt so far:
In terms of the unit step function, $u(x)$, we can express the probability as an integral:
$$P(X\ge c)=\int_c^{\infty}f_X(x)dx=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}u(x-c)f_X(x)dx.$$
However, I am stuck at this point and would appreciate any help to proceed further.
Update:
The Markov inequality states that for any non-negative random variable $Y$ and any $a > 0$, we have:
$$P(Y \ge a) \le \frac{E[Y]}{a}.$$
Now, let's consider $Y = e^{sX}$ for some $s > 0$. Then, we have:
$$P(e^{sX} \ge e^{sc}) = P(Y \ge e^{sc}) \le \frac{E[Y]}{e^{sc}} = \frac{E[e^{sX}]}{e^{sc}} = e^{-sc}E[e^{sX}].$$
But $E[e^{sX}]$ is just the moment generating function $M_X(s)$ of $X$. So, we have:
$$P(X \ge c) = P(e^{sX} \ge e^{sc}) \le e^{-sc}M_X(s).$$
This holds for any $s > 0$, so we can take the minimum over all such $s$ to get the inequality:
$$P(X \ge c) \le \min_{s \ge 0} e^{-sc}M_X(s).$$

There is a trick: $P(X \ge c) = P(s X \ge sc) = P(\mathrm{e}^{sX} \ge \mathrm{e}^{sc})$ for any $s > 0$.

Thanks for your hints, I updated my post, can you help to have a look whether it is a legal proof?

I think It is fine.

Nice, thank you again for your guidance!
